# Why am I returning null when I patch my data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I am patching my data, but when I do that my data ends up with the value of `null`. I even `console.log` the value that I am sending to my database and I get the correct value, but for some reason in my database it is showing up as null.

```
,    "going":null, "date":"2020-11-10T17:34:11.135Z", "__v":0},
ivs","going":2,    "date":"2020-11-11T04:19:24.433Z", "__v":0}]
```

As you can see, "going" should have an integer as its value, but instead the one that I patched shows `null`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Scroll extends React.Component {
    state = {
        posts: [],
        id: 0,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/posts/save").then((res) => {
            const posts = res.data;
            this.setState({ posts });
        });
    }

    handleClick = (id) => {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.state.posts.length; i++) {
            if (this.state.posts[i]._id === id) {
                let x = this.state.posts[i].going + 1;
                axios({
                    url: `http://localhost:5000/posts/save/${id}`,
                    method: "PATCH",
                    data: x,
                })
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log(x);
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        console.log("Internal server error");
                    });
            }
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="flex-container">
                {this.state.posts.reverse().map((posts) => (
                    <div className="post">
                        <h3 id="post-text">{posts.title}</h3>
                        <p id="post-text">{posts.body}</p>
                        <p>{posts.going}</p>
                        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(posts._id)}>Going</button>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your backend look like

Comment: when I patch with postman it works so I'm not sure if the backend is the issue

Comment: is `x` a number or what type? are you sending the request as json? usually i do data: JSON.stringify(_data)

Comment: x is a number @Jerryc

Comment: sending an object will looks better to me, so data: JSON.stringify({ x: x })

Comment: ok so I just sent it as an object as you stated above and I still get null. I'm really stuck

Comment: You should `console.log(x)` before you send the data, to verify it's what you expect before you send it to your server. And if it what you expect, you should debug your server code to understand if it's not using the value you expect (maybe it ignores `0` for example).